# Python - Selenium - Some elements found, but other not

Tags: python, selenium, tags

the first 10 'td' are found, but none of the other 800 or so. How come this is happening, its very frustrating.

I just want a list of all the TD on the that page, but only some are found even though all are visible.

```
driver.get("http://www.skyracing.com.au/index.php?component=racing&task=todayraces&Itemid=88&id=18")
heading3 = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td'))
count = 0
while count <= heading3:
    count = count + 1
    StringCount = str(count)
    try:
        heading4 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[" + StringCount + "]").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    print(StringCount)
    print(heading4)
```

Comment: Why not just loop over the list returned by `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td')`?

Comment: Are you saying that heading3 is coming back with a length of 10? It's hard to say what could be causing this without seeing the HTML, but if the length of heading3 is 10 then I would guess that you would need to use a different xpath.

Comment: Please provide us with the html code. It´s easier than to find an solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just loop over the list returned by `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td')`?

```py
for idx, elem in enumerate(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td')):
    print(i+1, elem.text)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, however it hasn't really answered the question.

Comment: Are you sure all those TDs are in the main document and not in one or more IFRAME elements?

Comment: Or perhaps you just need to WAIT for the other TDs to load.